# Guidance on where to start for a better foundation study

Tags: remix

I'm a newbie to the block chain technology, where should I start from as a bigger for a better masterly and successful learning?
Can I kindly get anyone who can offer to mentor me for the realization of my study?

Comment: Not sure what *Foundation* means in this context, but if the technical aspect of Ethereum is what you're interested in, then [this](https://ethereum.org/developers/) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Disclosure. I am one of the content creators and mentors for instructor-led offerings: https://academy.b9lab.com/courses/course-v1:B9lab+DISCOVERY+2019/about

Comment: The book "Mastering Bitcoin" (there is a free open source version) introduced me smoothly into Blockchain-based Cryptocurrencies with focus on Bitcoin. After that one can expand his knowledge to include the Ethereum Ecosystem with the book "Mastering Ethereum".